# What is the name of the decorative circle around verse numbers?

Tags: quran

On [this page](http://quran.com/10/27) there is a circular decoration around the Arabic ayah (verse) number:

[image: verse number circled]

What are these decorations called?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, can you please underline or highlight by doing simple image editing? Just fyi, info about punctuations can be found in this post http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/what-are-the-different-punctuation-in-quran

Comment: Ah, so it does refer to the text itself instead of Allah. I mean the circle around the ayah number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://muslimcanada.org/quran_division.html), it seems that the circles have no specific name, but they are used to indicate the ayah number:

> Ayah (pl. Ayat), Verses. Ayah is a word which signifies "sign." It was used by Muhammad for short sections or verses of his revelation.
>   The division of verses differs in different editions of the Arabic
>   Qur'an. The number of verses in the Arabic Qur'an are recorded after
>   the title of the Surah, and the verses distinguished in the text by a
>   small cypher or circle. The early readers of the Qur'an did not agree
>   as to the original position of these circles, and so it happens that
>   there are five different systems of numbering the verses:
>
> (a) Kufah verses. The Readers in the city of al-Kufah say that they
>   followed the custom of 'Ali. Their way of reckoning is generally
>   adopted in India. They reckon 6,239 verses.
>
> (b) Basrah verses. The Readers of al-Basrah follow 'Asim ibn Hajjaj, a
>   Companion. They reckon 6,204.
>
> (c) Shami verses, The Readers in Syria
>   (Shiim) followed 'Abdu 'lliih ibn 'Umar, a Companion. They reckon
>   6,225 verses.
>
> (d) Makkah verses. According to this arrangement, there
>   are 6,219 verses.
>
> (e) Madinah verses. This way of reading contains 6,211 verses.