# Is stopping at the one of the two pairs of three dots compulsory?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

For example: [image: Surah Al-Baqarah, Ayah 2]

I am aware that you can stop at either one of the three dots, but not both. However, sometimes I hear reciters not stop at all, is it compulsory to stop at either one of the three dots?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This stop represents a point where there are two acceptable (but mutually exclusive) ways to read a particular line.  In this particular example,

> 1. This is the book without doubt, in it is guidance for those who fear God.
> 2. This is the book; there is no doubt in it, a guidance for those who fear God.

To my understanding (see also http://www.ilmfruits.com/2008/tajweed-different-stops/), the stop itself is weighted the same as a [jeem stop (ج)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/4130/22), meaning it's a place you *can* stop if you want, but there's no particular recommendation one way or the other.  However, if you *do* stop at one you *must not* stop at the other otherwise the meaning is changed entirely.  So, for example, if you stopped at both points the line would be parsed thus:

> - This is the book, no doubt.  In it.  Guidance to those who fear God.

Comment: Ahh right, Jazakallahu Khayraan!

Comment: Great answer, thank you.