# Difference of waqf in Qiraat Hafs between waqf الوقف in usual Moshaf and turkish recitation

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, uloom-al-quran

When listening to Turkish qur'an reciters I often realize that they don't do waqf (stoping/pausing recitation) in typical places in Qur'an Verses according the Qiraa' of Hafs 'an 'Assim (in the most spread Saudi-Arabian print)!

Maybe in other countries who use the same Moshaf they have the same waqf positions and symbols (see also: [What are the different punctuation in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/what-are-the-different-punctuation-in-quran/37594#37594))! As I saw these (different) positions in a Turkish copy of Mushaf!

So what kind of waqf are they following, or more exactly to whom it refer's?

I know that in northern Africa especially in the Maghreb countries they used to follow the woqof al-Hibtiya الوقوف الهبطية according to Imam al-Hibti al-Fassy (850-930 a.H.) in Qiraat Warch 'an Nafi' (bi taryq al-Azraq) and even Qalun 'an Nafi'. So it may sound a bit strange or different if a reciter from the middle east used some other waqf!

For example in this [recitation on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_21PHZ7mF0) of ([2:285-286](http://legacy.quran.com/2/285-286)) the Qari' made  a (slight) waqf after the first rusulih (there is no waqf here!) and didn't consider doing it after doing it after 'irhamna (which is only waqf jaiz, so this is totally acceptable) but did it on each of the words before wa'fu 'anaa, wa-ghfir lanaa where again there's no waqf prescribed according the mushaf of medina (Hafs 'an 'Assim). Unfortunately I couldn't so far find better examples, as my question is based of what I've heard in mosques here in Germany myself!

Comment: If you can give me some example links to differentiate, that will be great. I have a good resource doing his P.hd in a similar topic, he will be able to give enough information to answer this. Though he will not give answer himself as his English is so weak and he is not into such platforms. Anyway, some links will be great.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal you mean examples of the waqf practice in the riwaya of hafs... i'll try to find them!

Comment: yes. That will help. Jazakallah

Answer (score 1):

The proper pausing (waqf) and starting (ibtida) while reciting is essential for a reader of Glorious Qur’aan. With an improper pause or start at a word or verse, the meaning of a sentence could be distorted. There are established methods for pausing and starting while reciting the Holy Qur’aan. A pause may occur due to one of the following reasons:

(1) pause because of a shortage of breath 
(2) Recommended pause 
(3) Mandatory pause. 
(4) prohibition of pause

there are  several ( at least two) vocalization - tarīqat al-dabt  writing the mushāfs

For several centuries, several different dabt (diacritical) systems have been in use. At least two for Hafs and two for Warsh recitation. For Hafs recitation, one used in primarily in Arab land and another use in Central Asia and the subcontinent mainly Non-Arabs lands

Although both use the Hafs recitation but slightly different in diacritical method (debt) and printing style.

The mushafs published in central Asia employed more waqf signs because it is assumed that readers do not know what they reciting more signs are placed to guide the reader.
Itfpause is made where it is not recommended - the reciter is obliged to go back  few word and continue without stopping

Comment: As is this only tangentially addresses the question. If you could add some details that would be more helpful. Beside waqf laazim is something specific for a reading as basically there's none of that in the quran as scholars say, waqf is a matter of ijitihad.