# Is it allowed to erase Harakat or Waqf marks from the Quran?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, uloom-al-quran, tajweed

As-Salamu alaikum, Is it allowed for me, when I create Quran vidoes (mushaf & audio) on YouTube to sometimes erase an Harakah or an Tawaquf sign when editing the videos? (For example, in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E26l7BcBmxA in the first ayah, you may notice that I've erased some dhamat to put the second line)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking none of these signs are part of the qur'an or the (original rasm of the) Moshaf.

You must know that the qur'an is the orally transmitted word of Allah it is not a physical book. The physical book actually is what we call al-Moshaf which contains the content of the qur'an. In the original manuscript there where only letters without any symbols or signs like diacritics.

The harakaat (diacritics) where added much later to help people (especially none Arabs) read and recite properly.
And the tajweed signs such as waqf, madd etc. signs have been added even later.
Scholars of the first three centuries would have even considered these "changes" in the original manuscript as illegal or bid'ah. But as they are beneficial it is fine to use them, but they don't have any relevance with the qur'an, as the qur'an is orally transmitted from generation to generation memorizing it by reading from a book or listening to a tape/video actually is wrong as there's no peer review.

So your changes actually are irrelevant to the qur'an, but actually are relevant for tajweed or for a learner who needs a book to exercise etc..

But as for the qur'an there's nothing that hinders you doing so unless you are afraid to cause harm.
IMO you should at least make a note or indication or we may even call it a "disclaimer" at beginning and end of the video that memorizing qur'an without peer support by a hafidh is wrong. I'm really afraid that later generations will do so and we will get a mess, as ignorant people would only follow a nice well sounding recitation without caring whether it is properly performed!

Maybe helpful:

- [What is the origin/purpose of the pause marks in the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41056/what-is-the-origin-purpose-of-the-pause-marks-in-the-quran)
- [What are the different punctuation in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/what-are-the-different-punctuation-in-quran)
- [How many spellings do exist for Quran's text? How many rasm-al-mushaf do we have?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/how-many-spellings-do-exist-for-qurans-text-how-many-rasm-al-mushaf-do-we-have)
- [Why do words like "salah" and "riba" have an extra unpronounced letter waw in them?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/why-do-words-like-salah-and-riba-have-an-extra-unpronounced-letter-waw-in-th)
- [Quran originally without vowel marks?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38179/quran-originally-without-vowel-marks)
- [Are the letter forms of Arabic essential to the Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47356/are-the-letter-forms-of-arabic-essential-to-the-quran)

Comment: I imagine you'd still want to be careful of removing signs that could actually change the pronunciation, for example removing a shaddah while keeping the vowel, or removing one half of a tanween'd double-vowel.

Comment: Jazakum Allah khayran, I've been trying to find an Muslim calligrapher that would do my profile picture and channel art for the sake of getting good deeds, not money. Can you help me in that?