# How to pronounce هُوَ in Surah Al-Hashr (59/22)?

Tags: quran, tajweed

I want to learn correct pronunciation of the `هُوَ اللَّهُ الَّذي لا إِلٰهَ إِلّا هُوَ`  (59/22). Go to this link for [related verse](https://www.kuranvemeali.com/hasr-suresi/22-ayeti-meali).
If we want to stop in first part, according to tajweed rules (Al-Madd Al-‘Aarid), last word is pronounced with Jazm like that: `هُوْ` (huv) . But teachers stop like that هُ (hû) . it means without sounds letter و.

You can listen this verse from teachers ([like him](https://youtu.be/0JKzRLSIPiE?t=39)), he does not sound letter وَ. Others teachers also does not sound it.
Why letter وَ is not read? What is the rule of it? I research a lot of Tajweed (quran reading rules) but I could not find the rule of it. Can anyone tell the rules with sources?

(This example also exists in surah al-Baqarah (2/255): `اللّهُ لاَ إِلَـهَ إِلاَّ هُوَ`.
Teachers does not sound last letter وَ in first stop part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ج sign after َهُو indicates that this is a position for waqf jaa'iz (permissible pausing/rest) according the tajweed rules of riwayat Hafs 'an' Asim. This means you have the choice to pause (which is marked by a silent diacritics - sukun- in the recitation) or go ahead reciting. So if you toke this opportunity and made a pause you'll recite

> هُوَ

Without pronouncing the fatha sign on واو. Now as the damah (ـُ) on the هاء (هُـ) has the same sound as the واو due to the sukun (ـْ) which marks the pausing on the (وْ) واو this sounds as if the واو is not pronounced at all as the damah sound is stronger than the silent sukun (the same would apply to fatha (ـَ) if the next and last letter was an ألف or kasrah (ـِ) if the next and last letter was a ياء).

Else you'll pronounce it.
The same basically may apply for verse 2:255.

See also [What are the different punctuation in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/4130/13438)

Comment: I know that it is not pronounced the fatha sign on و. But I know that letter ه and و must be jezm like that هُوْ. However teacher pronounce هُ. They does not pronounce letter و . Why Jezm rule is not applied? Is there any rule or it is applied only this verse and 2/255 (of course, if you want to stop there)

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı I've made an edit.

Comment: I could not find official site or rule but in this [link](https://www.mumsemaforum.com/misafir-sorulari/170808-kur-an-okurken-ayet-sonlarinda-durus-durak-nasil-olmalidir.html). He said that if the letters of med (`ي  و  أ `) comes to end of the verse, they are not pronounced, they extend previous letter pronounce. do you agree this rules?

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı I'm not an expert on Hafs 'an' Asim. It's not the reading I prefer for recitation although it's among the easiest. What I've quoted above is general practice. You can apply this to a letter that has the same sound as the diacritics of the prior letter in the case of three letters: the letters و in case of damah, ي on case of kasrah, and ا in case of fatha.

Comment: Thank you for effort. Allah bless you.

Answer (score 1):

When pausing in Arabic, the last letter's vowel can be ignored and be pronounced as a stop. Meaning as if it had a sukoon on it.

For example if the phrase is:

> إِلاَّ هُوَ

The هُوَ can be pronounced as as if it was a هُوْ

Similarly, if you are pausing at the end of the first ayah in Surah Fatiha, you would pronounce "رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ" as if it was "رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينْ" even though the "ن" has a Fathah on it.

However, if you are continuing rather than pausing, it has to be pronounced as normal.

Comment: You said that The هُوَ can be pronounced as as if it was a هُوْ. However teacher pronounced it هُو. I know pausing rules that last character pronounced with Jazm but this rules is not applied in this verse. You can listen this verse in this links: https://youtu.be/fAJf5yIIGu8?t=41
https://youtu.be/FL2XaLLhRRs?t=106
etc.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı The two are the same. When there is nothing above the letter, it usually means it is a jazm. If there is a jazm on a 'و' or if there is nothing over it, it means you have to elongate it. Meaning, you have to say "hooo"

Comment: That's it. I want to learn why/when we have to say "hoo". For example in surah al-fatiha, we sounds "Alhamdu lillaahi Rabbil 'aalameen", not ".. aalamee". We sounds the last letter نَ with Jazm previous letter مِ. What is the rule of it?

Comment: The rule is to sound it with a jazm. What I am trying to say is that having a 'و' with a jazm means you make a long "oo" sound. How do you think you would pronounce "هُوْ"? The correct answer is you would pronounce it "هُو" ("hooo") because they are the same thing.

Comment: I think that that they are different: "هُوْ" and "هُو". This is pronounced "هُوْ" = "hov", and this is pronounced "هُو" = "hooo". I learned it. You said that if Jazm and و comes together it means WaawSakin and it pronounced no harake and together with previous letter. For example surah bakara verse 8 (2/8): وَبِٱلۡيَوۡمِ ٱلۡأَخِرِ = [ve bil yevmil ahıri](http://www.kuran.gen.tr/?x=s_main&y=s_middle&kid=4&sid=2). Is it also wrong for you? Is Jazm always same for all letters?

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı They are not different. As far as I know, 'hov' is not a sound in the Arabic language. If it has a jazm, it would be 'hooo'.

Comment: In fact, some people write "يَومِ" instead of "يَوْمِ" because they are the same thing. But, the difference of why it is pronounced differently from "hooo" is that if a و comes after a letter with fathah َ  it is pronounced "ao". But, if it comes after a letter with a dhamma on it ُ it is pronounced "ooo". That is why it is Y*ao*m il-aakhiri

Comment: Also, see verse 22:61, يُوْلِجُ which is pronounced "y*ooo*lijo"

Comment: hmm. I didn't know و is changed according to fathah and dhamma. Thank you for enlighten me. But in your last example 22:61 there is no Jazm (يُولِجُ ٱلَّيۡلَ) in quran's which I looked 3 different website.

Comment: Is that jazm rule which you mentioned in the comment only necessary for letter و? Can you reference for this rule, thank you.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı Interesting that the websites don't show a jazm. My Quran app does. Just goes to show that they are the same thing. It depends on what style the writer is using. This is one website where you can see the jazm: https://www.quranexplorer.com/quran/default.aspx?Script=IndoPak

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. I didn' know this rule, I will research, thank you.