# I am confused about two different stopping signs, used at same point in different Mushaf of Quran

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, tajweed, reciting

I was reciting Surah Al Bqarah verse 256, at one point there is لا/قف and on other mushaf there is صلے

لا means stop is prohibited 
While صلے means stop is preferable.

I am so confused, please if someone can guide me.

It happened earlier in one ayat earlier as well.

[image: with stop sign]

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/what-are-the-different-punctuation-in-quran) post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the different punctuation in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/what-are-the-different-punctuation-in-quran)

Comment: @Sassir I am not sure that answers the question since this is a case of combining two seemingly opposite marks لا  and قف.

Comment: @UmH at least this looks like a Turkish/Pakistani Mushaf. Only people familiar with it could answer. As this doesn't appear in other Mushafs. However the applied ruling is that لا wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the books I looked at, the meaning of صلے is given as an allowed stop but not recommended. This means you can stop if you wish but it is better to continue.

Secondly, لا means "don't stop" while قف means "do stop."

So it is a bit confusing that both لا and قف are used at the same time in the picture you gave.

However, in my opinion, this appears to mean that the writers of the mushaf thought both are possible and are giving you the choice to choose.

It seems, in both books, the choice is given to you whether you wish to stop or not.

The meaning of the verse is not impacted either way. The verse being:

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion **(the stop or not-stop)** The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.