# What Should I Do When I See This Symbol in Quran

Tags: quran, tajweed

I've read Surah Yasin many times, but recently I got curious about a symbol in the Surah. I tried to find a solution in Internet by searching Tajweed rules: I found something similar but I am not sure if it refers to the same symbol.

This is an image of the symbol I'm asking about:

[image: Symbol]

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the information what kind of moshaf you found this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assalamualaikum,

Alhamdulillah, I can answer your question, brother (or sister).

You should stop reading for a second in this symbol but can't breathe (you should hold your breath). [Click here](https://everyayah.com/data/Abdurrahmaan_As-Sudais_192kbps/036052.mp3) to hear the verse.

This symbol is 4 times in Al-Quran.

- Kahf - 18:1
- Yaseen - 36:52
- Qiyamah - 75:27
- Mutaffifin - 83:14

Hope that the answer will be helpful for you.

Comment: Alaikumassalam, thank you for answering. Can you additionally provide the name of the symbol or a source link?

Comment: The sign is called _Saktah_. You can [click here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/what-are-the-different-punctuation-in-quran/4134#4134/#:~:text=%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%87:%20means%20one%20should%20stop%20here%20breaking%20the%20sound%20but%20not%20the%20breath.). For details, [click here](https://juliherman.wordpress.com/2014/10/12/pause-pause/amp/).