# Suah At-Taghabun Aya 9: Why do no reciters pronounce the Kasra at the end of ٱلتَّغَابُنِ‌ۗ?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, reading-quran

I have checked multiple reciters and two different sources. None of them pronounce the kasra at the end of the word ٱلتَّغَابُنِ‌ۗ
https://read.quranexplorer.com/64/9/9/Usmani/Khalil-Husari/Hide/Tajweed-OFF
https://quran.com/64

Comment: Oddly enough, quran.com has a feature for pronouncing individual words, and when you click on ٱلتَّغَابُنِ‌ۗ, it DOES pronounce the kasra, but not in the recitation of the aya.

Comment: In Arabic when you stop at a word we do not pronounce the last letter haraka in other words we make skoon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because it comes before a waqf sign (symbol), following or correctly applying it means one has to pronounce the last letter as sukun (soundless).

[image]

As this symbol "قلى" initiates a pause or stopping in the recitation. However it is permissible to continue the recitation and in that case you must recite the kasra.

For further information refer to [What are the different punctuation in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/4130/13438)